# Predilecto vs Favorito

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adjetivos

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'predilecto' y 'favorito'?

Se puede decir:

- Juan es mi hijo favorito
- Juan es mi hijo predilecto

¿Son iguales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En un principio te iba a decir que son sinónimas, pero luego pensándolo un poco más me da la impresión de que pueden tener connotaciones diferentes. Veamos las definiciones:

> **[favorito, ta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Hh5BEDz)**
>
> `De`*`favor.`*
>
> 1. adj. Estimado y apreciado con preferencia.

Y:

> **[predilecto, ta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TxpGTuJ)**
>
> `Del lat.`*`prae-`*`'pre-' y`*`dilectus`*`'amado'.`
>
> 1. adj. Preferido por amor o afecto especial.

Ambos adjetivos comparten en sus definiciones el uso de *preferir* ("preferencia/preferido"), pero en el caso de *predilecto* dice "por amor o afecto especial". Diríase que el "hijo predilecto" es aquel a quien más amas e "hijo favorito" es aquel a quien más aprecias, aunque puede ser por otros motivos diferentes al amor.

Nótese, por otro lado, que *favorito* tiene otros significados, que no se corresponden con la definición de *predilecto*:

> 2. adj. Que tiene, en la opinión general, la mayor probabilidad de ganar en una competición. U. t. c. s.
> 3. m. y f. Persona que tiene privanza con un rey o personaje.

En todo caso, yo diría que cuando ambos significan "preferido", en la práctica son bastante intercambiables. Podemos coger un ejemplo de *predilecto* del CORDE y ver qué pasa:

Original:

> El lugar predilecto de los amantes al deporte y al baile, a 15 minutos de Valencia, rodeado de pinos y flores.

Alternativas:

> El lugar favorito de los amantes al deporte y al baile, a 15 minutos de Valencia, rodeado de pinos y flores.
>   El lugar preferido de los amantes al deporte y al baile, a 15 minutos de Valencia, rodeado de pinos y flores.

No aprecio diferencias entre las tres versiones, más allá de que *predilecto* suena más culto, y *favorito* suena más corriente.

Comment: Coincido en que la mayor (o tal vez la única) diferencia es el registro. "Predilecto" es bastante más formal. Me recuerda a un pasaje bíblico: "Tú eres mi Hijo muy querido, en quien tengo puesta toda mi predilección”. Lc 3, 15-16.21-22.

Answer (score 0):

La segunda acepción de favorito puede darle cierto peso en determinados contextos. Por ejemplo si tus hijos están en una competencia, aunque quieras mucho a uno, puede que el otro tenga más posibilidades de ganar. Sería la única diferencia a grandes rasgos de una a otra palabra